# Surjectivity of induced map on cohomology for projective scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

*Note:* Below, cohomology means Čech cohomology.

(Liu, exercise 5.3.13) Let $X,S$ be locally Noetherian schemes, $f:X\to S$ a projective morphism and $\mathcal{F,G}$ quasicoherent sheaves on $X$ with a surjective morphism $\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$. Suppose that the fibers of $f$ are of dimension $\leq d$. I would like to show that $$H^d(X,\mathcal{F})\to H^d(X,\mathcal{G})$$ is surjective, and here's what I've managed to prove so far.

First off, let $\mathcal{K}$ be the kernel of the morphism $\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$. Then $\mathcal{K}$ is quasicoherent. Proposition 5.2.34 tells us that our assumptions ($f$ projective, $Y$ locally Noetherian, $\dim X_s\leq d$) imply the vanishing of the $p$:th higher direct images of *any* quasicoherent sheaf on $X$ for $p\geq d+1$. In particular, $$R^pf_*\mathcal{K}=0,\ p\geq d+1.$$
In other words, for every open affine $V\subseteq S$, we have
$$(R^pf_*\mathcal{K})(V)=H^p(f^{-1}(V),\mathcal{K}|_{f^{-1}(V)})=0,\ p\geq d+1\tag{$\star$}.$$
Now, from the short exact sequence
$$0\to \mathcal{K} \to \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G} \to 0$$
and quasicoherence of $\mathcal{G}$, we obtain a long exact sequence in cohomology containing the following piece:
$$H^d(X,\mathcal{F})\to H^d(X,\mathcal{G})\to H^{d+1}(X,\mathcal{K})$$
The surjectivity of the first arrow is equivalent to the vanishing of the last group, but is it possible to conclude that from $(\star)$?

If $[k]\in H^{d+1}(X,\mathcal{K})$, so $k=(k_\alpha)\in C^{d+1}(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{K})$ for some cover $\mathcal{U}$, I don't see how I can find a refinement of $\mathcal{U}$ for which $(\star)$ would be applicable.

*Edit:* It seems like the exercise is false as stated. Let $X=S=\mathbb{P}^1_k$, $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}_X$ and $\mathcal{G}=k(x) \oplus k(y)$ the direct sum of scyscraper sheafs supported at $x\neq y$. There is a natural surjective morphism of sheaves $\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$. Now, if $f:X\to X$ is the identity morphism (which is projective) then every fiber has dimension $0$ and the claim would imply that we have a surjection
$$k=H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to H^0(X, k(x) \oplus k(y))=k(x) \oplus k(y),$$
which is impossible.

Comment: For the short version, alas no. Take $p=1$ and $f$ to be the identity $X \rightarrow X$.

Comment: Right, thanks. Edited.

Comment: I think the question is false, too (instead we need to consider the higher direct images), but I’m not entirely sure. With again the identity map, then if the result holds, it follows that for every surjective map of two quasi-coherent sheaves $\mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$, the induced map on global sections is surjective. That’s very likely false (structural sheaf of $\mathbb{P}^1$ to a sum of two skyscraper sheaves, maybe).

Comment: Yes, I agree, thanks. I will try to find a different approach.